# Java Spring exclude count() from my request

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

I would like to get a list of data from my DB with filtration and limit offset option, but I do not need totalRows, how can I exclude count()?

Now I have this code

```
public interface CoreTransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<CoreTransaction, Long> {

    List<CoreTransaction> findAll(Specification<CoreTransaction> spec, Pageable pageable);

}
```

but in logs, I steel see count() request

> DEBUG 26316 --- [http-nio-9009-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(coretransa0_.id) as col_0_0_ from transaction.transactions coretransa0_ where coretransa0_.player_id=? and coretransa0_.operator_id=?

Comment: If you do pagination you need a total row count, how else are you going to determine the amount of pages?

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't put it right, we don't have basic pagination with page navigation, but just a button load more...

Comment: Then add it to your question. However when using a `Pageable` it will automatically (afaik) also issue the count. If you don't want that create your own query and set first/max results yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the type `Slice` instead of `List` as return type. A `Slice` does not have a total count so it will avoid the count query as well.